# Sub-menu creates extra space

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to make a vertical css menu with sub-menus. I've done some research and can't quite find an answer to my specific problem.
The ul within the li is positioned correctly (Edit: I'd like the first li in the li>ul to be inline with the li, "1" inline with "Two"), but the li containing the ul becomes larger, and I'd like that not to happen.
Example here:
http://cssdesk.com/PHPNv

Comment: Relatively positioned elements retain their place within the flow of the document no matter where you place them.  That's how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, but I made a couple of changes which should help you out.

```
nav li {
  background:#abcdef;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #9abcde;
  color:#000;
  display:block;
  padding:1em 0;
  text-align:left;
  text-indent:1em;
  text-decoration:none;
  width:100%;
  position:relative; /* need to add so nested elements are positioned relative to the current menu item */
}

nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute; /*need position absolute here to take it out of the 'flow'*/
  left:100%;
}
```